# Setting up Magento 2.1.1 Cronjob

Tags: cron, magento2

I am a bit lost on how to setup cronjob for Magento 2.1.1 in Cpanel using Cron Jobs. If someone could guide me that would be awesome. I did a search and I have 4 cron.php files in file manager.

> /public_html/store/vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/cron.php
>   /public_html/store/pub/cron.php
>   /public_html/store/update/cron.php
>   /public_html/store/update/dev/tests/integration/framework/cron.php

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/asulpunto-cronedit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this what you want to do.

1. Navigate to Cpanel
2. Open Cron Jobs
3. Add new job. In the Common Settings drop down option, select the Once Per Five Minutes option.
4. In the Command field enter  `wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron.php`  / make sure you use your domain name.
5. Click Add New Cron Job.
6. Take/make certain the newly created cron.php file is placed it in the root folder of your magento site.

That's it.

Comment: I went into File manager and checked the directory to see if cron created the file and it did not. What steps should I take? Thank.